# Is $e^{-x}x^\alpha$ Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: calculus

For any $\alpha\in \Bbb R$, show that $g:[1, \infty)\to\Bbb R$ given by $$g(x) = e^{-x}x^\alpha$$
is Lebesgue integrable.

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
If $\alpha>0$, then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\mathrm{d}x
=\int_1^\infty x^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-x}\mathrm{d}x
\le\int_0^\infty x^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-x}\mathrm{d}x
=\Gamma(\alpha+1)<\infty,
$$
and if $\alpha\le 0$ then $g(x)\le\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ for all $x\in[1, \infty)$ which is clearly integrable.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), answering questions without context and where the OP does not show any effort is not advised.